# Update a column values based on another column

Tags: python, dask

I've got two dataframes: the original one and a filtered one. I've added new items to the filtered one and now I want to update the values of the original one.

```
data["notes"] = None
filtered_data = data[data["security"] > 10]
filtered_data["notes"] = "my notes"
```

I've tried this but I get an error:

```
data.loc[data["uuid"] == filtered_data["uuid"], "notes"] = filtered_data["notes"]
```

> TypeError: '_LocIndexer' object does not support item assignment

I've also tried this but I get an error when computing the dataframe:

```
data["notes"] = data["notes"].mask(data["uuid"] == filtered_data["uuid"], filtered_data["notes"])
data.compute()
```

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Answer (score 0):

You could use panda's [masking](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-mask/#:%7E:text=mask()%20function%20return%20an,of%20the%20if%2Dthen%20idiom.) function

```
data["notes"] = None
df["notes"].mask(df["security"] > 10, "my notes", inplace=True)
```

df will contain a new column "notes" with None value except for rows where security is > 10.

Hope it helps!